# JavaFx set ImageCursor

Tags: java, javafx

I want to set an 16x16 image as my cursor, here is my
code:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(View.getInstance().getRoot(),1200, 640);

    Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/images/Cursor.png"));


    scene.setCursor(new ImageCursor(image,
                            image.getWidth() / 2,
                            image.getHeight() /2));

    System.out.println(ImageCursor.getBestSize(0, 0));
```

The last line I found by Googleing my problem it prints:

```
Dimension2D [width = 20.0, height = 24.0]
```

Edit: Ok this code seems to work on Windows.
Does someone knows how i can make it work on Linux,OS X?

Comment: The problem is that the cursor doesn't change and I thought that if you pass `0,0` it returns the max size of the cursor if you pass `16,16` its just `Dimension2D [width = 16.0, height = 16.0]`